# Regular expression for matching account numbers

Tags: regex

I need to match account numbers from a large text file. The account numbers will be in the following format:

> 1. Account Number : 123456
> 2. Acct 4567
> 3. Acct Number : 123-456-789
> 4. Account Number 134-456-789
> 5. Account#111111

I need a regex which checks each line starting with “Acc”, ignore white space and any special character and then ending with numeric.

I have written the following regex. The problem is that it matches some of the account number variants. example it matches #1 and #2 but not #3 and #4. 
The account numbers do not have fixed length and as you can see there are different variants of the string "Account Number"

Any help or advise on fine tuning this will be greatly appreciated.

```
(Acc[^0-9]*[0-9]*)
```

Comment: If doing this with a programming language, I would split each line on whitespace, and then use a conditional regex on the _last_ word to get the account number.

Comment: @c0deblack your question cause that I wrote blog post about fluent regular expression using VerbalExpressions: http://stapp.space/clean-code-regular-expression/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a more precise regex:

```
^Acc(?:oun)?t(?:\s+Number)?.+[\d-]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/bM5yB2/4

Comment: Thanks all for the quick response. I tried the solution suggested Stephan and Sebastian and both seems to work. However, in addition to account numbers it is also matching other patterns such as "Bank ID : 12345"; "Account Name : ABC" . ; "Account Address" etc. Any way to exclude these?

Comment: @c0deblack Does the regex need to match `"Bank ID : 12345"` and `"Account Name : ABC"` too?

Comment: No, it should match only the Account Numbers.